# End Canvas with touch up

Tags: android, canvas, graphic

I draw line with canvas and touch
But my problem is this that when we toch again the screen , the perivious line deleted
I want with touch again draw new line but the last line dont deleted
Tnx
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
        canvas.drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY, mPaint);
    }

```
// when ACTION_DOWN start touch according to the x,y values
private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
    sX = x;
    sY = y;
}

// when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values
private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
        eX = x;
        eY = y;
}
private void upTouch(float x, float y) {
    eX = x;
    eY = y;
}

public void clearCanvas() {
    invalidate();
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        startTouch(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        moveTouch(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        upTouch(x,y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: please paste some code.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/graphics/canvas-graphics/android-canvas-example/) a pretty good example for canvas and drawing

Comment: Tnx for your answer
I saw it before
In above link use this in upTouch:
mPath.LineTo(mx,my);

But  i cant use this because i draw a line not path

Comment: i attach it in the first post, its the second time i ask in this site, i want to insert my totally code in post but site eror

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not enough I will need at least all the places when you use these sX, eX etc. variables... or I can search an other tutorial for you :/

Comment: i insert all place that used sX,sY,eX,eY ,, and sry for my bad english

Comment: I think your problem is that you always rewrite the variables where you store the touch start and touch and, you should put them in a list like in the example above.

Comment: How i should do this? I dont have path so i cant use path.lineto

Comment: You can create an own class or store the start and and points in different arrays. In the example by Alex there is a custom class named Line, that's good for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code to get you started. Each time the user touches, a new `Line` is created and added to a list of `Lines`.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DrawLineView drawLineView = new DrawLineView(this);
    setContentView(drawLineView);
  }
}
```

**DrawLineView**

```
public class DrawLineView extends View {

  List<Line> lines;
  Paint black;

  public DrawLineView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // sets up a new list of Lines
    lines = new ArrayList<>(); 

    black = new Paint();
    black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    black.setStrokeWidth(5);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // for each of your Lines, draw them on the canvas
    for (Line line : lines) { 
      canvas.drawLine(line.xStart, line.yStart, line.xEnd, line.yEnd, black);
    }

    invalidate();
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Line line = new Line(event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getX(), event.getY());
        lines.add(line);
        break;

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        lines.get(lines.size() - 1).xEnd = event.getX();
        lines.get(lines.size() - 1).yEnd = event.getY();
        break;
    }
    return true;
  }

  class Line {
    public float xStart;
    public float yStart;
    public float xEnd;
    public float yEnd;

    public Line(float xStart, float yStart, float xEnd, float yEnd) {
      this.xStart = xStart;
      this.yStart = yStart;
      this.xEnd = xEnd;
      this.yEnd = yEnd;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tnx for your answer, but i am very Elementary , i dont underestand anything from ebove code , if is posible solve my problem with my own code, tnx

Comment: Sure. The problem with your code is that every time the user touches, the app overwrites the values of sX, sY, eX, and eY. The reason my code works is because every time I touch the screen, I create four *new* variables (which are stored inside my Line class), xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd and I add these to a List of values. This way, I don't overwrite the previous values. You need to create a List of values and every time the user touches you must add an entry to this List.

Comment: Tnx very much , i underestand what is problem , but what about this link? This is exactly like my code(except upTouch) and work corectly